# Accessibility options mangled keyboard input

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout, input-languages, accessibility

Someone messed up the accessibility settings on our Windows 10 PC and now when I log in the keys 7,8,9,0,j,k,l etc. are not working. After playing around with some Ease of Access settings the number keys started working but when I pressed k it would print 2, with L it would print 3 and so on. It works like this for some time but if I restart the PC it goes back to all those keys not working.

This only happens for 1 of the profiles on the PC. If you log in as a different user, the laptop's keyboard works normally.

The other surprising thing is that if I connect an external keyboard, then it works correctly for all user profiles.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is this a laptop?  If so, your problem sounds very similar to this famous question from November:  https://superuser.com/q/1143100/650163

Comment: Thank you! Num lock was on. Your link led me to the answer.